# Show a progressbar on datagrid data update

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, datagrid, progress-bar

It might sound like a trivial question but how can I show progress bars, when datagrids and other components that "talk" to web services, update their data providers

Answer (score 0):

Start the progress bar on sending the call to the web service, then cancel it when your datagrid sets the dataProvider. You override the public setter for dataProvider and cancel there.

Answer (score 0):

***Sorry giving response 2 years later but why not if it may help someone...***

You need to do some adaptation when using progress bar with remoting services (RemoteObject, HTTPService, WebService,...). That is :

- Set ProgressBar's **mode** property to the static constant **ProgressBarMode.EVENT**
- Set ProgressBar's **source** property to some custom object you have implemented and which extends from **EventDispatcher**
- Use your custom source object to **manually dispatch** event instance of class **ProgressEvent** with the type of **ProgressEvent.PROGRESS** to control the fill of the progress bar
- You set **ProgressEvent.bytesLoaded** and **ProgressEvent.bytesTotal** to control the fill i.e **ProgressEvent.bytesLoaded LESS THAN ProgressEvent.bytesTotal** when calling your remote service and **ProgressEvent.bytesLoaded EQUAL TO ProgressEvent.bytesTotal** when your remote service returns (in ResultEvent.RESULT listener for example)
- You can optionally set ProgressBar's **indeterminate** property to **true** since remoting are often async action with **indeterminate duration and amount of returned data**. Then you'll use **fake values** for **bytesLoaded** and **bytesTotal**